# How to prevent the selection of a specific color in a component TColorBox?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Does anyone know how to remove a certain color from the drop-down list of `TColorBox`?

[image]

Comment: Thank you all for your help. You all helped me a lot. The most suitable solution in my case is https://stackoverflow.com/a/45728378/8105226.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the color in the from the list:

```
procedure TForm7.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;
begin
  i := ColorBox1.Items.IndexOf('clGreen');
  if i <> -1 then
    ColorBox1.Items.Delete(i)
  else
    Showmessage('invalid color');
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

The prefilled ones you can delete from the [**Items**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomCombo.Items) collection. For example:

```
procedure TForm31.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Index: Integer;
begin
  Index := ColorBox1.Items.IndexOfObject(TObject(clGreen));
  if Index <> -1 then
    ColorBox1.Items.Delete(Index);
end;
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to do that in the IDE

Comment: @Nasreddine, try to drop down that combo list at design time :)

Comment: LOL. true but that is what the OP is asking. I think if you added that it can't be done on the object inspector and he needs to do it by code it would be better

Comment: @NasreddineAbdelillahGalfout, OP Wrote: *Using IDE: Delphi-2010*, which meant to be the Delphi version. I removed that part from the Q. its is already tagged "Delphi-2010"

Answer (score 3):

Your question title:

> How to prevent the selection of a specific color in a component TColorBox?

So prevent is not delete , and you have two choice:

- Prevent selection :

  ```
  procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   begin
    ColorBox1.ItemIndex := -1;
   end;

  procedure TForm1.ColorBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
  begin
  if ColorBox1.Colors[ColorBox1.ItemIndex] = clNavy then //Choose any color
    begin
      ShowMessage('Invalid color');
      ColorBox1.ItemIndex := -1;
    end;
  end;
  ```
- If you need to delete the `Color` then you have two answers to do that.

Comment: Deleting is the best prevention :) P.S. body says _"how to remove a certain color"_.

Comment: @Victoria As I say _If you need to delete_ :) , and he know what he want .